# Interactive slicing of dataframe columns using Bokeh

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I have below function which gives me an error - "expected element of list" in Python using Bokeh.

```py
data = {'Name':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18], 'Income':[202, 213, 194, 185]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
menu=Select(title="Columns:", value=df.columns[0], options=list(df.columns.values))
def showData(df):
    source = ColumnDataSource(df)
    columns = df[[menu.value]]
    data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns,width=900,fit_columns=True)
    return vform(data_table)

show(column(menu,showData(df)))
```

I should be able to see only the column i selected from filter in the output HTML - should return the results in table format. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`columns` should be a list of `TableColumn` objects as you can see in [the docs](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html#datatable). You'll have to use CustomJS or a Bokeh server to change the displayed column in the DataTable.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select, DataTable, TableColumn
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.io import show

data = {'Name':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18], 'Income':[202, 213, 194, 185]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
menu=Select(title="Columns:", value=list(df)[0], options=list(df.columns.values))
source = ColumnDataSource(df)
data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=[TableColumn(field=menu.value, title=menu.value)],width=900,fit_columns=True)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(), code="""
    console.log('Update tablecolumns code...')
""")

menu.js_on_change('value', callback)

show(column([menu, data_table]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried running your code, but getting this error - AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'js_on_change'

Comment: Try to update your version of Bokeh, it should work ;)